# Running python script on 400 csv files contained in the same folder

Tags: python, csv

I have 400 csv files and a python script I intend to run on each of them individually. 
After running the script on a single file, a resulting .csv file is produced. I want to store all the output .csv files in one folder, each with different names.

How do I make this happen all at once? 
Please help me write a python script for the same.

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? do all CSVs have similar data and operations to be performed? do you overwrite initial CSV file?

Comment: On a UNIX styles OS it wouls be a simple `xargs` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
list_of_files = os.listdir("folder_path")
for x in list_of_files:
    y=open(folder_path+"\"+x, "w")
    #your script here to produce a outout csv and save it
```

Comment: I tried the same but the value of 'x' is a string so it's throwing a FileNotFoundError

Comment: for f in os.listdir(folder_path):
        print(f)
        file_dataframe = pd.read_csv(f,low_memory=False)
        function_call(file_dataframe)

Error is being thrown at read_csv